# Searching for substrings in a string. There is also a delimiter. This is java

Tags: java, string, recursion, character, constants

I have a text file which contains strings. My problem is that I don't know how to search for specific strings. All I can appear to search for are certain characters. I need to make the code recursive.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class LangValidator {
    private static final char delimeter    = '$';
    public static boolean isValidString(String s) {
        //Hint: use a stack of characters:
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        int i = 0;
        char c;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == delimeter)
                break;
            stack.push(c);
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            c = s.charAt(i);
            if (stack.isEmpty())        return false;
            if (stack.pop() != c)       return false;
            i++;
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
```

//This is the part where I am having errors. I can search specific characters but when I try strings I get an error that I can only add character constants.

```
public static boolean isValidStringRec(String s) {
        if (s == null) return false;
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ch) if (c != '$' && c != 'b') return true;
        if(s == "$$$") return false;
        return false;


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            String str = fin.nextLine();
            System.out.println(str);
            System.out.println(isValidStringRec(str));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



}
```

Update: This is the input file:

```
$
$$$
a$a
abab$abab
ab$ba$ab$ba
aba$abaa
bbbaaa$aaabbb
aabb$bba
aba$aba
```

Comment: Side note: you use curly braces in some places and not in others. You should use them after all your for, if, while etc to make code clear and readable.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Based on your code for the method in question, as it appears to return false if the given string is made of only 3 $'s. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, could you confirm that the method is supposed to return true if none of the characters in the given string are '$' and 'b', and will return false in all other cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, based on our conversation here's a recusrive way to find if a string is a palindrome.

```
public static boolean isValidStringRec(String s) {
    if(s == null)
        return false;
    if(s.length() <= 1)
        return true;
    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return isValidStringRec(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
    return false;
}
```

It checks if the first and last characters of a given string
    are the same, and if so, tests to see if the rest of the string is a palindrome(substring is
    inclusive for the first parameter and exclusive for the second).

If the first and last characters of a given string are not the same, then the string is not a 
    palindrome and so will return false.

The only way to return true is if the string's length is if the string's length is either 1 or 0.
    it'll be 1 if the original string was of an odd length, meaning that all the previous pairs of 
    the string were the same, and so is a palindrome(like racecar), and a length of 0 if the original 
    string was of an even length and all the previous pairs of the string were the same(like anna).

It should be noted that this method will not work if the palindrome doesn't have to be case-sensitive,
    so if you need that as well either try to fix it or ask and I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the method is to return true only if none of the characters are `b` or `$`,
            and false in all other cirumstances, here's my solution.

It checks if the first character
            of the given string is either a `b` or a `$`. If that evaluates to false, then the string is
            not valid and it will return false. If that evaluates to true, however, then the method is given the
            string with the exception of the first character(which has already been checked), and
            continues the cycle.

Once the method checks a string that has a size of 0, it means that none
            of the characters are `b` or `$`, and so will return true;

I found checking if a string is `$$$` to be redundant as it'll return false anyway if the string contains a `$`.

I will change my answer accordingly if I misinterpreted your question.

```
   public static boolean isValidStringRec(String s) {
    if(s.length() < 1)
        return true;
    if(s.charAt(0) != '$' && s.charAt(0) != 'b')
        return isValidStringRec(s.substring(1));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to differentiate the different strings. Could you add that as part of your question or put more spaces between each string? Also, does my method do what you need? If not, what exactly should it do?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I should clarify. I have an input file that contains strings. I need the code to  read a string and determine
whether this string belong to the following language or not. Basically when the string is pushed in the stack it should keep going until it hits the delimiter which is the $. Then it will start popping back, for example....if I have a string aba$aba then that is part of the language. If I have a string abab$abab then that is not part of the language.

Comment: please help me @burrito77

Comment: I need somemthing to do this    if (s == null) return false;
        char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
        if(s == "$$$") {return true;}
        if(s == "a$a") {return true;}
        if(s == "aba$aba") {return true;}
        if(s == "bbbaaa$aaabbb") {return true;}
        {
     return false;
        }
    }    but it doesnt work

Comment: @Issajatt It doesn't work recursively, or it doesn't work at all? Also, could you add the expected outputs next to the inputs you gave? It seems like you're trying to see if the given string is a palindrome.

Comment: I believe so to. I understand what needs to be done, I'm just having trouble with the coding.

Comment: @Issajatt I posted another answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much @burrito that is exactly what I need. I need to do more research with palindromes.